# I am using the phonenumbers module in python trying to figure out a numbers carrier. After entering the number it prints nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, phone-number

I am using the phonenumbers module in python trying to figure out a numbers carrier. After entering the number it prints nothing. Here is my code

```
import phonenumbers 

import phonenumbers.carrier 

num_object = None 

while num_object is None: 
    try: 
        num = input("phone number:         ") 
        num_object =         phonenumbers.parse("+1     {}".format(num), region="US") 
except Exception as error: 
    print("ERROR: {}".format(error)) 
      
carrier =     phonenumbers.carrier.name_for_number(n.   um_object, "en") 
print(carrier)
```

The output is blank.
How do I make it say the name of the carrier?

Comment: You appear to have a typo in `carrier =     phonenumbers.carrier.name_for_number(n.   um_object, "en")`. There is a `.` between the `n` and `um_object`. Also, is there a reason there are multiple spaces scattered around?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
>>> from phonenumbers import carrier
>>> ro_number = phonenumbers.parse("+40721234567", "RO")
>>> carrier.name_for_number(ro_number, "en")
'Vodafone'
```

https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/